# Prove that the normal form of a closed term in the STLC of simple type contains no lambdas or applications.

Tags: logic, computer-science, type-theory, lambda-calculus

Suppose that we have a **closed** term `x:t` in the simply typed lambda calculus (STLC) (i.e. this term does not contain any free variables). You can use the terminology and syntax definitions given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus#Syntax).

Suppose that `t` is not / does not contain a function type, e.g. in the case of a simple programming language perhaps `t` can be expressed in the following (inductive) grammar:

```
ty := Int | Bool | Unit | Array ty
```

It is a theorem that the STLC is strongly normalizing under beta-reduction (e.g. see the first point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus#Important_results)). I want to prove that this implies that the normal form (under beta-reduction) of `x:t` does not contain any lambda abstractions or applications. If the proof is simple, great. Otherwise a link and a high level description would be nice.

If this is not true, a counter example would be great.

(**NOTE**: an original formulation of this question was answered by [@Taroccoesbrocco](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/288417/taroccoesbrocco), but I had forgotten to specify closed which is important for my situation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you want to prove is false, unless you implicitly suppose more hypotheses that you should make explicit.

For instance, take the simply typed terms $x : \text{Int} \to \text{Int}$ and $y : \text{Int}$, for some distinct variables $x$ and $y$. Then, $xy: \text{Int}$ is a *normal* (with respect to $\beta$-reduction) simply typed term that contains an *application*, and whose simple type is *ground* (that is, not a function type).

Could we weaken your statement by only demanding that the simply typed term does not contain any abstraction? No!
A counterexample is the following: take the simply typed term $x : (\text{Int} \to \text{Int}) \to \text{Int}$ and $\lambda y^\text{Int}.y : \text{Int} \to \text{Int}$, for some variable $x$ and $y$. Then, $x(\lambda y.y): \text{Int}$ is a *normal* (with respect to $\beta$-reduction) simply typed term that contains an *abstraction* and whose simple type is *ground*.

---

*Edit after the OP edited his question.*

If you add the request that the simply typed term must be closed, then the property you are interested in (the $\beta$-normal form of every closed simply typed term of ground type does not contain any abstraction or application, that is, is a term constant) is true, provided that every term constant is typed with ground type (which is usually the case).

Indeed, it is easy to prove that every closed $\beta$-normal form is either an abstraction or a term constant (this is false if a constant can be typed with an arrow type).
But abstractions cannot be of ground type, they are necessarily of arrow type. Hence, every closed simply typed $\beta$-normal form whose type is ground is a constant.
To conclude (since the property talks about every simpled typed $\lambda$-term, not only the $\beta$-normal) just use strong normalization (as you correctly mentioned) and [subject reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_reduction) (that is, if $M:\tau$ and $M \to_\beta N$, then $N : \tau$).

Comment: Great answer! However, the situation I'm interested in the term is also closed, i.e. contains no free variables. I should have specified this before, but your answer helped me realize that I forgot to say this.

Comment: @martin - I edited my answer to answer the new version of your question.

Comment: @martin - True, but imposing that every free variable has ground type it's very restrictive since it essentially amounts to give up any higher order feature (the key feature of the $\lambda$-calculus) on those variables.

Comment: @Tarocooesbrocco Space is limited, see "answer below"

Answer (score 0):

The reason I'm interested is because I have a STLC like syntax tree in a programming language which contains lambda abstractions and applications, but I must remove these features as part of compilation. A top level program in this language is a term of ground type constructed via a DSL where the only free variables are introduced for user input. In this case, user input must be restricted to constants of ground type.

I had implemented beta-reduction in order to remove the lambda applications and abstractions from the syntax tree, and was unclear if this was enough. I have yet to see a program fail to compile, but didn't have a theoretical basis to believe this was enough.